# Why $\Delta_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\Delta_n(S^1)=0$ for $n\geq 2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

I find it difficult to understand it when I read Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*. In Example 2.2, I can understand $\Delta_0(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$. But how to illustrate why $\Delta_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\Delta_n(S^1)=0$ for $n\geq 2$?

Comment: I'm not quite sure where your confusion lies, since $\Delta_0$ works the same way as $\Delta_i$ for all other $i$. Hatcher chose a $\Delta$-complex structure with one $0$-cell, one $1$-cell and zero $n$-cells for $n \geq 2$. So $\Delta_0 = \Delta_1 = \mathbb Z$ and $\Delta_n = 0$ for $n \geq 2$. (I'm not sure if I should put this as an answer instead of a comment since I didn't really write anything different than Hatcher and so I also don't know whether this helps you.)

Comment: @QiZhu You should write an answer.

Comment: @PaulFrost Ok, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hatcher chose a $\Delta$-complex structure on $S^1$ with exactly one $0$-cell $v$, one $1$-cell $e$, and zero $n$-cells for $n \geq 2$. But $\Delta_i(S^1)$ is the free abelian group generated by the open $n$-simplices of $S^1$. In other words, we count the number of $i$-cells to find the rank of $\Delta_i(S^1)$ and obtain $$ \Delta_i(S^1) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z}v \cong \mathbb{Z} \quad & i = 0, \\ \mathbb{Z}e \cong \mathbb{Z} & i = 1, \\ 0 & i \geq 2. \end{cases}$$